# list of states with the total number of units that have been sold to that state

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, delete-row

I am still new to SQL, and have to complete the tasks at hand. The task is:
A "fake" user has made a few orders. DELETE the user account along with all of their orders.
This means delete from 3 tables:
ORDERDETAIL
ORDERS
CUSTOMERS

ORDERDETAIL and ORDERS have a FK of ORDERID, and ORDERS and CUSTOMERS share a FK of CUSTOMERID. I started to use this code:

```
DELETE ORDERDETAIL.ORDERID
FROM ORDERDETAIL
INNER JOIN ORDERS
ON ORDERDETAIL.ORDERID = ORDERS.ORDERID
WHERE ORDERS.CUSTOMERID = '12341';
```

Just to start, but even this fails.

What code can I use to delete all rows that share the same ORDERID in ORDERDETAIL and ORDERS as well as CUSTOMERID from CUSTOMER and ORDERS?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a *subquery* to find the `orderid`s that you want to delete in a child table:

```
delete from orderdetail where orderid in (
     select orderid from orders
      where customerid = '12341'
);
```

Then you're able to delete the corresponding orders:

```
delete from orders
 where customerid = '12341';
```

*If* your tables are set up with a [cascading delete](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php), you can just execute the 2nd delete statement (without first going to execute the first statement).